# What I did wrong with Db::getInstance()->insert('product', $dimension)); not inserting data to database?

Tags: prestashop

I am developing a module that would save a custom field from product admin.. but my code is not inserting data into database.. below is my code.

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
    if(Tools::isSubmit('submitDimension'))
    {
        $name = Tools::getValue('name');
        $length = Tools::getValue('custom_length');
        $width = Tools::getValue('custom_width');


        if(empty($name) || !Validate::isGenericName($name))
            $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('Invalid name');
        if(empty($length) || !Validate::isGenericName($length))
            $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('Invalid length');
        if(empty($width) || !Validate::isGenericName($width))
            $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('Invalid width');

            if(!$this->errors)
            {
            $dimension = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'custom_length' => $length,
                'custom_width' => $width

            );

            if(!Db::getInstance()->insert('product', $dimension));
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Error while updating database');
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me please..

Here is my install function

```
function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || 
            !$this->alterProductTable() ||
            !$this->registerHook('extraright') || 
            !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra') || 
            !$this->registerHook('actionProductSave') ||
            !$this->registerHook('actionProductUpdate') || 
            !$this->registerHook('header')
            )
        return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my alter table function

```
 private function alterProductTable($method = 'add') 
        {
            if($method = 'add')
                $sql = '
                    ALTER TABLE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product 
                    ADD COLUMN `custom_length` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL, 
                    ADD COLUMN `custom_width` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL,
                    ADD COLUMN `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL';

                if(!Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))
                    return false;
                return true;
        }
.. the columns are there..

And here is my display admin hook
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
    {
        $name = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT `name` FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE id_product = '.Tools::getValue('id_product'));
        $length = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT custom_length FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE id_product = '.(int)Tools::getValue('id_product'));
        $width = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT custom_width FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE id_product = '.(int)Tools::getValue('id_product'));
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'length' => $length,
            'width' => $width
        ));
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/adminProductsExtra.tpl');
    }
```

I have been looking at this for 2 days.. and I cant seem to find what I did wrong.. I have gone to prestashop forum but no help so far.. I hope I can get something from good people here. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you check the Prestashop db best practice guide if not than please check first.
This is not the correct way to insert data you also need to mention fields in which you want to insert data particular table.
[Best Practices of the Db Class - Prestashop](http://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51184692#BestPracticesoftheDbClass--insert())

Comment: i did.. i added the other functions for you to see..hope you can help me..

Answer (score 0):

All is wrong, you are trying to insert data in a table which have many other fields required, and you are trying also to insert data in columns that doesn't exist in that table. The best way to create new products by code is using their object, like this...

```
$product = new Product()
$product->id_tax_rules_group = 1;
$product->redirect_type = '404';
$product->name = array(
    $id_lang => 'Product name in this lang',
    $id_lang => 'Product name in this lang',
);
/*
 * And so on all the mandatory fields
 */
$product->save();
```

Comment: I am confused.. I followed the convention at prestashop docs.. this is the query:  $dimension = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'custom_length' => $length,
                'custom_width' => $width

            );

            if(!Db::getInstance()->insert('product', $dimension));